# SeaweedFs: how to set max size for each volume?

Tags: seaweedfs, weed-fs

When I start the master service I can specify the maximum volume size with the parameter `-volumeSizeLimitMB`.

`./weed master -mdir="." -volumeSizeLimitMB=1000`.

Then, I start two volume services.

`./weed volume -mserver="localhost:9333" -dir="." -max=10`

`./weed volume -mserver="localhost:9333" -dir="." -max=10 -port=8081`

I have some questions:

1. How can I specify the maximum volume size when I start the volume service? Does it know it straight away because the master service communicate this to the volume service when it connects? I understand max is for the max. number of volumes, but how about the size of each single volume?
2. The master creates volume 8 and 11 on one volume service and 9 and 10 on the other, then it states "No space left". I don't understand why. Here is the whole log: https://pastebin.com/cLRd8gvt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The master controls which volume is writable. When it reaches the `volumeSizeLimitMB`, no writes will be sent over to the volume servers. So the volume server does not need to know the `volumeSizeLimitMB`.